# Xamarin and data binding

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to develop for multiple mobile platforms using only one programming language.
I found [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) to be quite interesting since I really like to use C#.

But I have one question which I couldn't find an answer to.

I'm a big fan of WPF and MVVM design pattern. Do Xamarin's GUI libraries provide rich support for data binding similar to that of WPF?
Is MVVM pattern easy to apply in Xamarin applications?

Comment: Have you *tried* using Xamarin.Forms? It's MVVM-based. Of course, you don't have to use Xamarin.Forms for your whole app, but you should feel fairly comfortable with it. As it is, this question isn't specific enough to be able to give a concrete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xamarin Forms](http://xamarin.com/forms) provides an MVVM model and data binding mechanism.  Forms also supports XAML.  [MVVMCross](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMvvmCross%2FMvvmCross&ei=_jBhVN37Npb6oQSIrYCgBA&usg=AFQjCNGbqInX-bg7V0ih6S1ZqPpJO0UmGg&bvm=bv.79189006,d.cGU), a third-party framework that is popular with many Xamarin developers, also supports data binding.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin Android do not, out of the box, have a strong data binding mechanism.